# IOS Memory Management and Application Foreground/Background

Tags: ios, memory-management

In my IOS application, I have a NSDate* property that is marked as `retain`

When My application becomes active again, the properties value has been released.

Did I misunderstand how properties and memory management work, and how can I guard against this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its obvious that something is sending a release or dealloc message somewhere.
If I were you I would create a deep copy like:

NSItem *ref = [[NSItem alloc] initWithData: x];

As far as finding out what is happening to that item in question I suggest you use NSZombie as an env variable as step through the call stack to see where its getting released.

Best of luck!